# What does the R2 mean in Code Geass?

Tags: code-geass

The second season of *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion* is suffixed with *R2*.  C.C's and V.V's names, while written with the dot between them they are pronounced as C2 and V2.

So I am wondering what the R2 in the title means: is it similar to how C.C's and V.V's names are writen and pronounced and it's supposed to be written as R.R? Does it mean something?

Answer (score 6):

As chocking as it may sound R2 stands for **second season**.

There is no information that it could mean something else or at least I haven't found anything to back other information such as R2 being things like:

- Round 2
- Rebirth 2
- Rewrite 2
- related to the CG power overtaking both eyes
- a 3rd element (such as c2 or v2)

If I had to name it, it would be "2nd Rebellion" as a continuation to the 1st season.

While there could be some crucial information provided on the manga that could clear I honestly don't recall any and perhaps some one could reinforce what I am saying.

Comment: release 2 maybe?

Comment: IIRC each episode is called a turn (of chess). So "round" keeps up with the chess theme.

Comment: Round 2 sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

Lelouch Lamperouge 
(Rurushu Ramperuji) = R.R. thus R2 - R2 (R.R.) is his code name like V2 (V.V.) & C2 (C.C.) had.

Comment: This was contradicted by the show creators on the audio commentary track. They explained that R2 stands for all possible, relevant words starting with R: rebellion, round, revolution, etc

Answer (score 1):

There is a theory going around that Lelouch isn't actually dead. (I don't know if you've heard of it or not but I'll explain it anyway.)

The theory basically says that in the episode "The Ragnarok Connection" when Charles wraps his arm around Lelouch's neck and strangles him, he does so with his hand that holds his code. The theory states that in this moment, Lelouch stole Charles's code and this is how Charles died. As a result of taking the code, Lelouch becomes immortal and survives being stabbed by Suzaku. This is where the R2 comes into play. Because Lelouch is now supposedly immortal, he has a name like C2 and V2.

Comment: This was contradicted by the show creators on the audio commentary track. They explained that R2 stands for all possible, relevant words starting with R: rebellion, round, revolution, etc